# Questions about h[:key] and h["key"] in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mongodb

I wrote this simple program in Ruby

```
h = {}
h["a"] = "1"
h[:a] = "2"

puts h
h.each { |k, v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" }
```

Which outputs

```
{"a"=>"1", :a=>"2"}
a => 1
a => 2
```

I have a few questions about this code which involve **`:` and `"` as indexers not by themselves**

1. When would I use one over the other? I originally found out there was a difference when certain mongo/rails functions I was calling were depended on the `:` indexer, while when I parsed json only `"` indexers were present.
2. Are there other ways to index a value with a key?
3. Is there a way for my `each` to recognize the difference between `:` and `"` indexers? It seems that `puts` was able to determine but `each` was not

Answer (score 0):

`{}` creates and empty Hash

`:key` is a `symbol` and `'key'` is string

Please first of all refer this about **[Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html)**